# Are there any BitTorrent Sync protocol details out in the wild?

Tags: synchronization, network-protocols, bittorrent, bittorrent-sync

Just wondering if anybody has reverse-engineered the protocol yet or has a link to a more or less official protocol specification or implementation (i.e. source code).

How much does it rely on the BitTorrent protocol ? How does it extend it ?

Answer (score 3):

[Picosync](https://github.com/picosync) intends to communicate with bit torrent sync. Another related project can be vole.cc mentioned here. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/7WUj3nASuLo